# Snakemake process multiple files in one rule

Tags: snakemake

What is the best way to process a list of files in one rule?

### Workflow

The main goal of the workflow is to select the raw data and output the selected data. The directory of the workflow is structured as below.

```
.
├── data
│   ├── 000_raw
│   │   ├── 15_a.csv
│   │   ├── 15_b.csv
│   │   ├── 15_c.csv
│   │   ├── 16_a.csv
│   │   ├── 16_b.csv
│   │   └── 16_c.csv
│   └── 010_sel
│       ├── 15_a.csv
│       ├── 15_b.csv
│       ├── 15_c.csv
│       ├── 16_a.csv
│       ├── 16_b.csv
│       └── 16_c.csv
├── scripts
│   └── 010_sel.py
└── Snakefile
```

The selection script `010_sel.py` read and produce one file at each time, i.e. the common way to run it is

```bash
python scripts/010_sel.py data/000_raw/15_a.csv data/010_sel/15_a.csv
```

### Snakefile

I use `expand` and `run` method in the snakemake file.

```yaml
ls_year_type = [15_a,15_b,15_c,16_a,16_b,16_c]

rule sel_010:
    input:
        expand("data/000_raw/{year_type}.csv",year_mag=ls_year_type)
    output:
        expand("data/010_sel/{year_type}.csv",year_mag=ls_year_type)
    run: 
        for ifile in range(len(output)):
            os.system("python scripts/010_sel.py {} {}".format(input[ifile],output[ifile]))
```

### Problems

There are two problems with this method.

- The `expand` command generate a list. If only one of the files in the list is modified, for example,`rm data/010_sel/15_b.csv`, snakemake will rerun the scripts on every file in the list. It is time consuming.
- If the script `010_sel.py` is modified, snakemake will not know it. Need to rerun the snakefile manually.

### Optional method

One optional way is to rewrite the `010_sel.py` to include snakemake commands rather than using `sys.argv`

```py
for i in range(len(snakemake.input)):
    input_file = snakemake.input[i]
    output_file = snakemake.output[i]
```

In snakemake file change `run` to `script`

```yaml
script:
    "scripts/010_sel.py"
```

This will solve the second problem but the first one remains.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Snakemake is a workflow manager with many features including parallelization, error recovery and code change awareness. It allows to define the logic of a process and apply it to many samples using wildcards, scaling it as needed.

By defining a for loop inside a rule, you're a basically loosing all the features above.
Here's how you (probably) should do it:

```
ls_year_type = [15_a,15_b,15_c,16_a,16_b,16_c]

rule all:
    expand("data/010_sel/{year_type}.csv",year_mag=ls_year_type)

rule sel_010:
    input:
        "data/000_raw/{year_type}.csv"
    output:
        "data/010_sel/{year_type}.csv"
    shell: 
        "python scripts/010_sel.py {input} {output}"
```

and running snakemake with:

```
$ snakemake --jobs 5
```

adjust the number of parallel job as needed, depending on your computer or HPC.

You can also use the `script` tag as you state. Snakemake will create a python object containing the command line arguments that you can process in the script:

```
rule sel_010:
    input:
        "data/000_raw/{year_type}.csv"
    output:
        "data/010_sel/{year_type}.csv"
    script: 
        "scripts/010_sel.py"
```

By doing it this way, you're letting snakemake taking care of the scaling. If one of the input file is changed, snakemake will only re-run the rule on the changed file. If the code of the script is changed, snakemake will re-run all the files. You can also change this behavior by using the snakemake option `--cleanup-metadata`